# Помогите пожалуйста в коде. Выдает ошибку

Tags: python

```
input('Оцените развлекательный комплекс:')
searching1 = 'весело'
searching2 = 'увлекательно'
searching3 = 'развлечения'
feedback = (searching1+searching2+searching3)
feedback = feedback.lower('весело' , 'увлекательно' , 'развлечения')
length = feedback
print('Результат анализа:',len(length))
```

Написал код, выдает ошибку:

```
[6:0] lower() takes exactly 1 arguments (4 given)
```

В ЧЕМ ДЕЛО ПОДСКАЖИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА

Comment: вам же "русским по белому" выдает, что `.lower()` может принять только один аргумент, а вы суете ему 4

Comment: Интересная конечно идея: просить пользователя оценить, но его ответ никак не учитывать, всегда считать результат анализа как сумму длин трех слов 'весело' , 'увлекательно' , 'развлечения'

Comment: @insolor и в конце главное не забыть добавить `"ваше мнение очень важно для нас"`

Comment: Да ну учится человек, что вы уж прям. Хотя для начала пусть учится читать, что в ошибке написано, тут я согласен )

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает потому, что метод lower() для строк в Python принимает ровно один аргумент — строку, к которой нужно применить операцию нижнего регистра. В вашем случае вам нужно применить метод lower() к каждой из переменных searching1, searching2 и searching3, а не передавать их как отдельные аргументы в lower().

```
searching1 = 'весело'
searching2 = 'увлекательно'
searching3 = 'развлечения'

# Объединяем три строки в одну feedback
feedback = searching1 + searching2 + searching3

# Преобразуем feedback в нижний регистр
feedback = feedback.lower()

# Вычисляем длину строки feedback и выводим результат
print('Результат анализа:', len(feedback))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Алина, если этот ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте его как [**принятый**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (галка напротив ответа).